# render jinja2 template without a Flask context

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Flask application that calls `flask.render_template` without problems when it is invoked from a flask `http request`.

I need the same method to work outside of flask (from a python back end program)

```
resolved_template =  render_template(template_relative_path, **kwargs)
```

I could use the `jinja2 api`, but I  would like the same method to work, in both contexts (flask and command line)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to render it in an app context.  Import your app in your backend code and do the following.

```
with app.app_context():
    data = render_template(path, **context)
```

Answer (score 30):

If you want to completely bypass `flask` and use purely `Jinja` for rendering your template, you can do as such

```
import jinja2

def render_jinja_html(template_loc,file_name,**context):

    return jinja2.Environment(
        loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_loc+'/')
    ).get_template(file_name).render(context)
```

And then you can call this function to render your html

Comment: Better yet, just use Flask's own default jinja environment with `app.jinja_env`.

Comment: What do you pass in to that function? Especially with ```template_loc```?

Comment: for some reason passing `template_loc+'/'` doesn't work for me, instead pass template_loc and make sure you add the `/` at the end

Answer (score 1):

What I use is this code:

```
import jinja2
template_values = {
  'value_name_in_html': value_name_in_python,   
}

template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template("file_patch")
self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Comment: It's complaining JINJA_ENVIRONMENT is not set.  How should I set it ?

Comment: Hi @blissweb, I am sorry I have not used Jinja in like 4 years so this info is not at the top of my head at the moment. If I get a chance later today I’ll look at it and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this simple steps to create and render a Jinja HTML template without using Flask. I use it to create email newsletter templates for my WordPress blog:

```
from jinja2 import Template

# Create a template string
template_string = """
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, {{ name }}!</h1>
</body>
</html>
"""

# Create a template object from the string
template = Template(template_string)

# Render the template with context data
rendered_template = template.render(title="My Example Page", name="John Doe")

# Print the rendered template
print(rendered_template)
```