# Loading page in flask web app while scraping another website using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium, flask

I am struggling with an application I want to make, which is a web application that will scrape an other website using the selenium package with chromedriver.
I am using python 3.7 on elementary OS.
Everything works okay if I don't include the loading page, even if I didn't put it online yet so I dunno for sure, but my problem is that I would like to let the crawling headless and no sandbox, while having the waiting page in my app.
I'd like to render to a success html template when the job is done, too.

I searched on stackoverflow for answers, but I couldn't make my thing work. (sorry if duplicate)
One thing that I found is Luiz Aoqui's answer to this question : [Flask is not render_template before executing long function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109084/flask-is-not-render-template-before-executing-long-function) , and it seems like the OP could solve his issue.
I couldn't, though.
I don't know javascript at all so maybe you will find this very simple, if the problem came from here.

The python flask code :

```py
@app.route('/auto_connect/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def connect():
    if session['mail'] != None:
        if request.method == "POST":
            session['job'] = request.form['job']

            return redirect(url_for('process', fun='auto_connect'))
        return render_template('auto_connect.html')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))   

@app.route("/process/<fun>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process(fun, *args):

    if fun == 'auto_connect' or fun == 'auto_apply':
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('wait.html', fun=fun)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            print('test')
            if fun == 'auto_connect':
                auto_connector(session['mail'], session['password'], session['job'])
                return 'done'

            elif fun == 'auto_apply':
                auto_applyer(session['mail'], session['password'], session['job'], session['location'])
                return 'done'
            else:
                return "error"
    return 'error'
```

The JS code :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/process/'.concat({{fun}}));

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status === 200 && request.responseText === 'done') {
    // long process finished successfully, redirect user
    window.location = '/success/' ;
  } else {
    // ops, we got an error from the server
    alert('Something went wrong. FROM server');
  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // ops, we got an error trying to talk to the server
  alert('Something went wrong. TO server');
};

request.send();
```

The loading page is showing, but the scraping does not start.
I expect it to start with the "open" POST request in the js code which is part of the 'wait.html' template.

PS : there is the flask debugger, I put a print at the top of my scraping script which shows up in terminal when I do no render the loading page, but doesn't when I do.

```sh
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2019 02:03:20] "GET /auto_connect/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2019 02:03:22] "POST /auto_connect/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2019 02:03:22] "GET /process/auto_connect HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself to my question.
I am not a web programmer so I lack some automatism sometimes, but by inspecting my waiting page, I saw an error in the JS script in the concat function.
Calling `'{{fun}}'` in the script instead of `{{fun}}` did the thing.

I didn't understand this behavior since my object fun is a python string, but I read the jinja2 doc and all became lucid to me, we can see in this link  https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/ the following:

```
{{ ... }} for Expressions to print to the template output
```

This prints the value, so it is no longer a string but raw text in html template.
(type(print(x)) is None in python3 btw)

If this helps someone then I'm glad.